# Angular ng-view onload not called when template changed

Tags: angularjs, routes, onload

I have a simple SPA which is being delivered statically using Node/Express, and then running completely client side. In index.html I have an ng-view attached to `<body>` for my route specific templates:

```
<html ng-app="PortfolioSPAModule" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <base href="/">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/dist.min.css">

    <script defer="defer" data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-save="true" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js" data-pin-build="parsePins"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-view onload="console.log('hi!')">

  </body>

  <script src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/dist.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Nothing surprising here. My app is contained in dist.min.js. The main app is defined here:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('PortfolioSPAModule', ['ngRoute']);

  function config ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        controllerAs: 'viewModel'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'about/about.view.html',
        controller: 'aboutController',
        controllerAs: 'viewModel'
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }

  // Add the config to our app.
  angular
    .module('PortfolioSPAModule')
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', config]);
  })();
```

Notice in index.html I've defined a simple console output for body onload. It is my understanding that onload is supposed to be triggered any time the template is changed according to this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/E259J/12/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=E259J

and this article: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/11/11/understanding-angularjs-directives-part2-ng-view/.

In my app, the body's onload method is only being triggered once during the pages' initial load.

Does anyone have any clue why this might be happening? Is this expected behavior?

I'd also appreciate some additional information around ng-view. When I look at my html in Chrome dev tools, I don't see any of my included scripts specified. what is ng-view doing to any scripts I add? Is it running them once, then hiding them? Can they be re-run again? Should the attached scripts be aware of any changes to the template being included in ng-view?

Any information about how ng-view works in this regard would be helpful!

Comment: you really shouldn't have ng-view on body. Body is only loaded once.  ng-view should be on a <div> within body

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my issue with included scripts disappearing. Strangely though, it doesn't look like onload is being called at all anymore.

Comment: onload should be a function defined in your controller